# Inserting different parts of a record at different times when writing to database

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-xe

My problem is that I'm writing data to separate fields in the same record at different times, and when I add data to the second set up fields in that same record, I get an error saying :

> You must enter a value in the 'tblWorkoutDetails.Username' field

Despite having entered that data in the previous statement.

The table this refers to is called `tblWorkoutDetails` and has the following fields:

- WorkoutID
- Username
- WorkoutDate
- Weight
- Waist

**WorkoutID and Username** make up a composite key. This table is relational to another table, which I'm also writing data to in the same way.

I'm writing the first part of my record (the fields making up my composite key) to the database using this code :

```
adotblWorkoutDetails['Username'] := Username;
adotblWorkoutDetails['WorkoutID'] := CurrentWorkout+1;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Post;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Refresh;
```

The values being assigned to the fields are simply variables and this executes perfectly.

The second statement which fills out the remainder of the fields in that record is as follows:

```
adotblWorkoutDetails['WorkoutDate'] := Date;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Weight'] := Weight;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Waist'] := Waist;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Post;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Refresh;
```

The program breaks with the aforementioned error at `adotblWorkoutDetails.Post`. While trying to fix this, I've attempted reassigning the required fields, however I got an error saying I was entering duplicate data. In addition, when I fill out every field in the record within the first go (using sample data to fill out the fields 'reserved' for the second data entry), the code executes perfectly, and so does the code writing to the other table.

I can't work out how to resolve this. If you need more information / screenshots of the code please ask.

This code gives me the 'you must enter a value in the field...' error:

[image]

And uncommenting these two lines gives me the duplicate data error:

[image]

Comment: The message "you must enter a value in the 'tblWorkoutDetails.Username' field" is coming from code in your application, not Delphi library code.  So, you need to add the code which includes this message to your q.  Likewise the code which contains the message saying you are entering duplicate data.

Comment: try adding **showmessage(adotblWorkoutDetails.fieldbyname('WorkoutID').AsString)** right after your first **adotblWorkoutDetails.Refresh**.  Do the same for the **username** field.  Make sure they are indeed set.

Comment: MartynA - I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. I haven't written any validation containing a message with that error, if that is what you're getting at. Also please see edit for code screenshots.

Comment: M Schenkel - I know these fields are set as I can view the database as soon as the first data input has occurred and those fields are displayed with the correct data, which is my problem, as it almost seems like it is forgetting that data is already entered in my record and so doesn't need to be amended, and yet when I do amend it, it sees the fields already contain data and won't let me post it.

Comment: That message isn't coming out of thin air, it must be in your code or some unit you're using.  Anyway, you still haven't posted enough of your code;  where do you call "adotblWorkoutDetails.Edit" after your first .Post to enable the additional changes to be applied to the dataset?

Comment: You append a **new** record where you should **edit** the current record

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what's happening is that your second operation is mistakenly doing another **insert** rather than an **edit**, and that the exception you're getting is the result of the *UserName* field having it's `Required` property set to `True`.

This works the way you're describing:

```
adotblWorkoutDetails.Insert;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Username'] := Username;
adotblWorkoutDetails['WorkoutID'] := CurrentWorkout+1;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Post;
//adotblWorkoutDetails.Refresh;    // Refresh is not required

adotblWorkoutDetails.Insert;
adotblWorkoutDetails['WorkoutDate'] := Date;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Weight'] := Weight;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Waist'] := Waist;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Post;
// adotblWorkoutDetails.Refresh;  // Again, not required
```

What you should be doing instead:

```
adotblWorkoutDetails.Insert;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Username'] := Username;
adotblWorkoutDetails['WorkoutID'] := CurrentWorkout+1;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Post;

// Locate the correct record using Locate or FindKey first, then 
adotblWorkoutDetails.Edit;
adotblWorkoutDetails['WorkoutDate'] := Date;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Weight'] := Weight;
adotblWorkoutDetails['Waist'] := Waist;
adotblWorkoutDetails.Post;
```

(As an aside for future reference, **never** post any of your code as an image; if you need to post code, copy and paste the code itself. [Here's a list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) of reasons why you shouldn't.